# How can I turn a simple iterative loop into a feeder in Gatling?

Tags: scala, gatling

In order to populate a system with data en masse before running performance scripts, our ideal use-case would be to do so with Gatling. Data need not be different, beyond having a unique Primary ID.

```
object Object {

 val create = repeat(4, "n")
 {
 exec(http("Create Object") 
 .post("/our/api/objects")
 .body(ELFileBody("CreateObject_0001_request.txt"))
 .check(status.is(201)))
 }
}

val createObjects = scenario("ModularSimulation").exec(CreateObjects.create);

setUp(
 createObjects.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

The above example can create any number of objects by changing the value of the `repeat`, however at large scales (e.g. 100,000 objects) it becomes impractical to do this linearly. So what I would like to do is have a shared pool of objects to be created by, say, 100 users.

This is - of course - the use case for a feeder. Rather than generate a static `.csv file` or use `Redis` it seems simplest to use a simple iterative loop (e.g. `0` to `100000`).

I know (from [documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/session/feeder.html) and other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348845/simple-feeder-in-gatling-without-using-a-csv-file)) that Feeder is a type alias for `Iterator[Map[String, T]]` so I presume this should be very straightforward - but I can't seem to find a *simple* example of this most basic case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want not achieve, but working with feeders is easy.
Suppose you have:

```
import scala.util.Random

// An infinite feeder generating random strings 
// accessible under "yourInfiniteSessionKey" from session  
val infiniteFeeder = Iterator.continually(
  Map("yourInfinteSessionKey" -> Random.alphanumeric.take(20).mkString)
)

// A finite feeder (in sense of possible values) 
// accessible under "yourFiniteSessionKey" from session
// it contains just 2 values for illustration purposes
val finiteFeeder = (for (i <- 0 until 2) yield {
  Map("yourFiniteSessionKey" -> s"I'm finite $i")
})

// A fixed feeder (again in sense of possible values)
// accessible under "yourFixedSessionKey" from session
// again it contains just 2 values for illustration purposes
val fixedFeeder = Array(
  Map("yourFixedSessionKey" -> s"I'm fixed 1"),
  Map("yourFixedSessionKey" -> s"I'm fixed 2")
)

val scn = scenario("Feeding")
  .feed(infiniteFeeder)
  .feed(finiteFeeder)
  .feed(fixedFeeder)
  .exec(http("root")
  .get("/${yourInfinteSessionKey}/${yourFiniteSessionKey}/${yourFixedSessionKey}"))
```

Just for a sake of example our scenario takes from all our feeders and use the values to compose GET request against "/".

In this case `fixedFeeder` is `Array[Map[String, _]` and `finiteFeeder` is `IndexedSeq[Map[String, _]`. If the number of items in your finite feeders match your setup it is ok so and you can run the scenario, e.g. like:

```
setUp(
  scn.inject(atOnceUsers(2))
).protocols(httpConf)
```

Setup has just two virual users thus it will run without an issue.
When you have more virtual users in your setup, e.g.:

```
setUp(
  scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1) during(30.seconds)) // equals 30 virtual users
).protocols(httpConf)
```

you will run into the problem with finite/fixed feeders and Gatling will complain about it and your simulation will stop like this:

```
[error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine
[error]     at io.gatling.core.action.SingletonFeed.feed(SingletonFeed.scala:59)
[error]     at io.gatling.core.action.SingletonFeed$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SingletonFeed.scala:28)
[error]     at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
```

Good news is that you can make you finite/fixed feeders infinite using on of Gatling API methods of [RecordSeqFeederBuilder](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/feeder.html#recordseqfeederbuilder), e.g.:

```
// Now the feeder from fixed values is infinite
val fixedFeeder = Array(
  Map("yourFixedSessionKey" -> s"I'm fixed 1"),
  Map("yourFixedSessionKey" -> s"I'm fixed 2")
).circular // go back to the top of the array once the end is reached
```

You can also use such API method calls directly in scenario definition and leave your fixed/finite feeders untouched, like:

```
val scn = scenario("Feeding")
  .feed(infiniteFeeder)
  .feed(finiteFeeder.random) // now is finiteFeeder infinite
  .feed(fixedFeeder.circular) // fixedFeeder is infinite too
  .exec(http("root")
```

Enjoy

Comment: How about if I don't want to have a static atOnceUsers value. I want it to depend on the size of my feeder? The only thing I could think of is by doing .readRecords and getting the size of the feeder.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer Teliatko, also when you need an infinite feeder based on a finite one, you can add toArray.random or circular like this :

```
val infiniteFeeder = (for (i <- 0 until 2) yield {
  Map("yourFiniteSessionKey" -> s"I'm finite $i")
}).toArray.random
```